Able to see the list of users without login to Superset. How to block this?
Able to see the list of users without login to Superset. How to block this? I would like to see List Users after login to Supserset. Steps to replicate the issue.

Don't login to Superset
Click on settins in the home page
Click on List Users

I should not be able to see the users without login.
